# c# express: where is my picbox?

Tags: c#

I am not a visual studio programmer but I need to whip up a quick app to display an image and manipulate it's height and width using a slider.  I've done the quick google and all of the information talks about using picturebox(picbox) as the image containing control but I don't seem to have a picbox control in my VS C# express install.

Should it be missing?  How do I get it back or install it?  What are my alternatives?

Comment: You are building a Windows Forms app or a WPF app?

Answer (score 4):

If you've looked carefully in the toolbox and couldn't find it, you may have accidentally deleted the icon. Right click on the "All Windows Forms" section header in the toolbox and select "Choose Items". Check the checkbox near the "PictureBox" control. It'll show up in the toolbox.

In WPF, you should be looking for the "Image" control instead.

Answer (score 0):

It was that I was in a WPF project rather than a windows form project like Mehrdad pointed out